# Do Google or Amazon cache content that's being delivered to their smart speaker devices?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, actions-on-google, google-home, amazon-echo

Is any caching of audio files done by Google or Amazon as audio content is being delivered to Google Home or Amazon Echo? I've read that developers do set up their own CDN for these purposes, but it's not clear if any caching happens during delivery or if audio is delivered directly to user devices from the publisher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge no, they do not cache responses as a large point of the assistant apps is to provide customised experiences to each user.

The one thing I might not be so confident on however is the inline SSML `<audio>` tag. There seems to be no information on the [Alexa documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/speech-synthesis-markup-language-ssml-reference.html#audio) or the [Actions on Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/ssml#audio) on this about caching, so I'd assume they don't.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean but you can find back your full Google Assistant history at https://myactivity.google.com/myactivity. This includes audio files with your spoken queries.